# Is there any reason why I can't use the PayPal Rest API in an Android app?

Tags: android, rest, paypal

I'm looking over the documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

And it appears that there's no reason why I can't make these REST calls straight out of my android app.

The reason I'm asking is that they also have an Android SDK, which, like other third party SDKs opens an ugly PayPal Activity. I was hoping to avoid having to use that, but want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious before I sink a bunch of time into development. Curious if anyone has implemented the REST api in either an Android or iOS app directly and if there are any problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not make REST API calls from the app directly. Always make it from server to avoid revealing your client ID and secret key.

Comment: ok, but in essence you're saying it's perfectly ok to wrap this functionality around my own UI in my Mobile apps and not use the SDK provided by PayPal, right?  And have you actually tried it, or are you just offering me general good practices advice?

Comment: if you are talking about wrapping your web app with a mobile app (mobile web app as opposed to native mobile app) - all your calls will be made from your server side- so in such cases yes you can call the REST apis directly. But keep in mind the PCI requirements as the payment info will flow through your server.

Comment: If you are talking about directly making REST api calls from your native mobile application - then you would need to embed your clientID/Secret in your mobile app, and as @mido said you will be compromising your own account security by doing so. So I would recommend using our Mobile SDKs. If you have any feedback on how we can improve our SDKs, please let us know.

Comment: I was offering a general good practice, very important one :)